# What if Redis triggers a snapshot in the middle of transaction?

Tags: transactions, redis, backup, snapshot

Say i have set my Redis backup with snapshot every few minutes, and unlucky when a snapshot is triggered, a transaction (use pipeline) is in the process. How does Redis deal with this situation? Will snapshot be delayed until transaction finished? Or save the first part of transaction? Or exclude the whole transaction until next backup?

Answer (score 1):

Keep in mind that Redis is a single-threaded event loop. A transaction is applied atomically when the EXEC command is executed. So either the RDB background save process is forked before the EXEC, or after the EXEC. You can consider that the fork takes an instantaneous snapshot of the memory of Redis.

If the EXEC is applied before the fork, then your transaction will be in the resulting dump. If the EXEC is applied after the fork, your transaction will not be in the dump, even if Redis takes minutes to generate it. Nothing will be delayed (neither the transaction, neither the dump).

On a side note, except if your database is tiny, doing a dump every few minutes is probably too heavy. Perhaps you should consider using the append-only file instead.